# hierarchical representations of verb meanings

Tags: verbs, vocabulary, semantics

Nouns can quite easily be represented in semantic hierarchies...

[image]

...with "hyponyms" serving as specific instances of "hypernyms."

**Q: Does anyone know of similar representations of verbs?**

Some notes:

- I'm looking for *systematic* representations of *semantic* relationships
- I'm not looking for categorization of verbs by behaviour (for this, we can turn to books like *English Verb Classes and Alternations* by Beth Levin, which does argue that verb behaviour is determined to a great extent by meaning but does not arrange verbs hierarchically)
- I'm not looking for *WordNet*, which groups words into "synsets" but does not represent verbs hierarchically

As an example: "get" can have the meaning of "come into possession of"; branching down from that meaning, we can identify "obtain" and "acquire," which mean "come into possession of by unidentified methods;" below "obtain/acquire," we might divide into "find" (come into possession of by chance), "receive" (come into possession of passively), and "procure" (come into possession of actively); below "procure" we might have "buy/purchase," "steal," "trade for," and so on.

Thanks in advance! And if the crowd feels that this question would find a better home in the Linguistics Stack Exchange, please let me know.

ADDED: I understand that in computer science hyponymy is expressed as an "is-a" relationship. How do computer scientists express the relationship among commands or actions?

Comment: It would be very helpful (not to mention civil) for downvoters to provide some rationale.

Comment: I've tried sketching this out on my own in the past, and it's always fallen apart because of 1) ambiguities between classes (is "magenta" a "red" or a "blue"?  Is "violet" a "purple" or a "flower"? does "to have" go under "to be" or "to do"?) 2) Even when you consider multiple meanings as separate words, a category's unifying concept might not have a single word to describe it, or if there is one, it's more abstruse than I'm comfortable with. 3) Sometimes there are orthogonal conceptual streams, e.g., look/see, listen/hear, touch/feel, sniff/smell.

Answer (score 2):

Hierarchies are useful when they arise naturally and have metaphoric hooks.
But hierarchies require [an `Up/Down` dimension](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Metaphors.pdf), and that's not present in some perceptual fields.

Verbs use taxonomies, of various sorts, since there are various sorts of verbs.

Here's an example of a taxonomy of [English Verbs of Unaided Human Locomotion](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/words/), an unfinished web project I set up as an example for the students in my lexical semantics class.

And here's another example, a taxonomy of [English Verbs of Cutting](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/cutting.pdf), with the various subclasses and dimensions of distinction (most of which are not hierarchical) laid out.

Those are for actions, which are complex, but observable.
There are also taxonomies for verbs of perception, emotion, and thought,
which are complex but unobservable.

For instance, many verbs subcategorize according to [Stative/Inchoative/Causative](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3A15299%20stative%20inchoative%20causative) dimensions.
Or [Presupposed/Entailed/Asserted/Denied dimensions](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/predtypes.pdf).
Or any of a range of other possibilities.

Comment: Thanks John Lawler! Your English Verbs of Unaided Human Locomotion is particularly interesting. I'm curious about your statement "hierarchies are useful when they arise naturally and have metaphoric hooks." Two things: 1) if hierarchies are systems of representation, how do they arise naturally? Would organisms have suggested their own taxonomies if Linnaeus hadn't beat them to it? 2) by "metaphoric hook," do you mean a "tree-like" structure?

Comment: Not necessarily tree-like. Slime-mold-like is probly a better metaphor. Concentric classes can generate natural hierarchies, matryoshka-like -- though one must still determine which direction is `Up` -- but mostly they're spinoffs from other clines or binary dimensions with some other metaphoric source for the vertical dimension (`More`, `Good`, `Alive/Active`, `Rich/Powerful`, etc).

Comment: @Rusty: You could say organisms suggest their own taxonomies through their DNA, in much the same way some "semantic taxonomies" may be suggested by etymology. But I don't really think *semantic categories* (or *words* corresponding to those categories) necessarily have a a potentially useful underlying hierarchical structure. Just as you couldn't meaningfully create a single hierarchical structure containing all the information on the Internet (How many categories would you have at the top level, for example? And what would be "good" top-level categories?).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I certainly don't presuppose feasibility here. And no, they don't necessarily have an underlying structure. But some semantic categories do, i.e. hypernomy and hyponymy of nouns. I'm curious: does the example I provided ("get" et al.) not suggest that we may, in fact, be able to represent verbs in this way?

Comment: The basic level categories are mostly  projections of human body parts and their uses. [Properties of entities (i.e, noun-like thingies)](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/frawleyentities.pdf) and [general properties](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/frawleyq.pdf), from Frawley.

Comment: @John Lawler: I was interested to see your Verbs of Cutting - A Sample Ontology. Particularly the use of "ontology" with respect to verbs. Does that suggest that we can, in fact, divide and subdivide (thus creating hierarchies) actions (verbs), not just noun-like thingies?

Comment: @Rusty: I dunno. What other "high-level" subcategories would you have besides (the single?) "acquire/obtain" under "get"? Where would you fit *"I don't get the joke", "Come inside or you'll get wet", "I hate him! And one day I'll get him [back]"*, etc.?

Comment: The system would certainly have to account for polysemy. We wouldn't nest "get" as in "understand" and "get" as in "become" under "get" as in "come into possession of." Those other meanings would have to have their own branching structures. But I do suspect that, if this were possible, the high level categories would be those common Anglo-Saxon verbs that demonstrate great semantic flexibility, like "give," "have," "make," and "do."

Comment: Read Frawley and Foley and see what you think. Not to mention Levinson's _Pragmatics_. These are just takeaway notes from the textbooks I used in the class.

Answer (score 0):

How about the following?

**Move**

Walk, run, cycle, drive, ride.

**Ride**

Ride a horse,
Ride a motorcycle,
Ride on a bus.

Comment: Thanks WS2. However, I'm looking for something more catholic and systematic, rather than a couple more examples. And the "ride" example doesn't divide "ride" into more specific verbs.